# Vincular a mi cuenta de usuario una pregunta que hice como invitado

Tags: soporte, perfil

Resulta que ayer hice una pregunta (la primera vez en este sitio) y la hice como invitado (con el nombre de *PJCM*)
Esta fue la pregunta:

[Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dump'"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158252/exception-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-dump?answertab=votes#tab-top)

La cosa es que, luego, me llegó el típico aviso al correo de que acababa de hacer una pregunta, con el enlace típico para que termines de registrarte dando un nombre y una contraseña.
No tenía, de primeras, intención de registrarme pero, al final, lo hice poniendo la contraseña y el nombre. Pero un nombre (*zacktagnan*) diferente al que puse cuando mande la pregunta como invitado.

Entonces, la pregunta es:
¿se puede, de alguna manera, vincular esa pregunta de PJCM a la que, ahora, es mi cuenta, es decir, a la de zacktagnan?

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Gran pregunta. Ni siquiera se me había ocurrido que esto se podía hacer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tal y como se explica en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts has de ir a la página de [Contacto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact) y rellenar el formulario bajo el problema "Necesito combinar perfiles de usuario":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]